# Create Individual log files for each project using enterprise library 5.0 logging

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

I am using MS enterprise logger for my application. My usecase is  to create different log files for each project in the solution. I have defined  app.config for each project.

Proj1 => writes to Log1.txt, Proj2 => write to Log2.txt and Proj1 references proj2.

Application is started from proj1. When messages are logged, the logs from proj2 are written to Log1.txt instead of Log2.txt.

How can this problem be solved. I am a newbie to Enterprise Library.

Thanks in Advance